# In magento how to send encrypted password in email

Tags: magento

Can anyone help me out.

In magento while the customer creating a new account a email will be sent, in that i need to send the password in encrypt format.

Comment: Sending password on registration is quite unnecessary. You can send a secrete key instead that can verify the email address. Is it absolutely necessary in your case?

Comment: Yes absolutely i need to send the encrypted password.

Comment: Encrypted how? So the user can decrypt it? Using what kind of key?

Comment: Good question. Actually we can use bcrypt class it is secure and we cannot decrypt it. Thats the way.

Comment: What point is there in sending the user a password that he can't decrypt? What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: Its just simple i need to send the password in the email with encrypted format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long research i found that there is a variable password_hash magento. It uses the hashing method to encrypt a password which cannot be decrypted.

**Code**

Just replace the code 
{{htmlescape var=$customer.password_hash}} 
in your email template instead of 
{{htmlescape var=$customer.password}}.